# UserProfile db showing (None) in django

Tags: django, forms

I was dealing with user authentication in django and created a UserProfile model with foreign key to User in-built model. Then I created explicitly defined User model and then deleted it to restore the original code.

But now in my UserProfile database accessed from admin page is showing (None) for all the profiles created earlier.

[image]

And when I click on it it shows an error.

[image]

This is the code:

forms.py and models.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from cms.models import UserProfile

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('designation',)



from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

How do I delete that (None)?

Comment: it's because your `__str__()` or `__unicode__()` built-in method prints this user, can you please show your code?

Comment: Have edited and added the code.

Comment: Why you didn't copy past your code

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry.

Comment: How do I suppose to copy your code, to help you

Comment: Have added code. Thanks.

Comment: I already typed the code myself and posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comments, it's because your  `__unicode__()` built-in method prints this user

Try change this part of the code to:

```
def __unicode__(self):
     try:
         return self.user.username
     except:
         return "UserProfile has No User instance"
```

Comment: `The user matching doe not exists` ? this ?

Comment: `__unicode__()` is the equivalent of `__str__` of python3. It is a method called whenever you call str() on an object. Django uses str(obj) in a number of places. Most notably, to display an object in the Django admin site and as the value inserted into a template when it displays an object.

Comment: So because your instance didn't have a `User` instance whereas you tell Django to show `self.user.username` it raises an error